# CNN autoencoder with non square input shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have implemented a CNN autoencoder which does not have square shape inputs. I am bit confused. Is it mandatory to have a squared shape input for autoencoders ? Each of the 2D image has a shape of 800x20. I have fed the data according to the shape. But somehow the shapes are not matching when the model is built. I have share the code of the model and the error message below. Need your expert advise. Thanks.

```
x = Input(shape=(800, 20,1)) 

# Encoder
conv1_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_1)
conv1_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_2)
conv1_3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
h = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_3)

# Decoder
conv2_1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_1)
conv2_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_2)
conv2_3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up2)
up3 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_3)
r = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up3)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=r)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

results = model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs = 500, batch_size=16,validation_data= (x_test, x_test))
```

Here is error:

```
    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((16, 800, 24, 1) vs (16, 800, 20, 1))
```

Comment: Could you please share also the error message you get? In general, autoencoders work also with "non-squared" shape inputs

Comment: Please do not show code/errors as images, include the text in the question itself. And you should include your model.fit call.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have updated the post and added the error and fit. Please have a look now.

Comment: What is y_train here? Autoencoders are supposed to reconstruct the input, so you do not provide additional labels for the task.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for figuring this out. But still I am getting the same error after replacing y_train with x_train. I have updated the error code. Please have a look.

Comment: You forgot the padding=same in the second-to-last conv layer.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy After adding the padding, the shape has changed and still similar errors.
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((16, 800, 24, 1) vs (16, 800, 20, 1))

Comment: @AMA, i have modified the code and it should work with you data now. do test it out and read the guidelines that i mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error trace indicates, the issue you are facing in trying to work with this autoencoder is that the model is expecting the input shape to be `(?, 800, 20, 1)` but, the output shape is `(?, 796, 20, 1)`. While it is getting each image input and output as

`(800, 20, 1)`. *(Check your model summary's input and output shape!)*

#### My Recommendations -

1. I have fixed with `padding = 'same'` and re-adjusted the shapes so that the input tensor shape and the output are the same. Check out the kernel sizes that I have modified to get the output shape as needed.
2. On top of that, for a stacked conv encoder-decoder architecture (such as auto-encoder) it is recommended that you translate the spatial information into feature maps/filters/channels with subsequent layers. Right now you start with 8 filters then move to 4 in the encoder. It should be more like `4->8->16`. Check this diagram for reference towards the intuition.

[image]

With the above recommendations, I have made the changes here.

```
x = Input(shape=(800, 20,1)) 

# Encoder
conv1_1 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_1)
conv1_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1_2)
conv1_3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
h = MaxPooling2D((2, 1), padding='same')(conv1_3) #<------

# # Decoder

conv2_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_1)
conv2_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_2)
conv2_3 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up2) #<--- ADD PADDING HERE
up3 = UpSampling2D((2, 1))(conv2_3)
r = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up3)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=r)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_13"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)        [(None, 800, 20, 1)]      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_101 (Conv2D)          (None, 800, 20, 4)        40        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_45 (MaxPooling (None, 400, 10, 4)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_102 (Conv2D)          (None, 400, 10, 8)        296       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_46 (MaxPooling (None, 200, 5, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_103 (Conv2D)          (None, 200, 5, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_47 (MaxPooling (None, 100, 5, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_104 (Conv2D)          (None, 100, 5, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_43 (UpSampling (None, 200, 10, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_105 (Conv2D)          (None, 200, 10, 8)        1160      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_44 (UpSampling (None, 400, 20, 8)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_106 (Conv2D)          (None, 400, 20, 4)        292       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_45 (UpSampling (None, 800, 20, 4)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_107 (Conv2D)          (None, 800, 20, 1)        37        
=================================================================
Total params: 5,313
Trainable params: 5,313
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To show that the model now runs let me create a random dataset with the same that you are looking at.

```
x_train = np.random.random((16,800,20,1))

model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 180ms/step - loss: 0.7526 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 189ms/step - loss: 0.7526 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa85a9896d0>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I modified my model according to your suggestion and it only runs for a single epoch and then again the same error.

ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 800, 20, 1) vs (None, 3))

Comment: can you print your X_train and y_train images shape? I think this is to do with your training data shapes. I am able to run the epochs for randomly generated data

Comment: Also, in the `validation = (x_test, y_test)`, change it to `(x_test, x_test)`

Comment: added my epoch runs to the answer. you can see that it runs for the shape (16, 800,20,1) as x_train

Comment: It worked after changing validation = (x_test, x_test). Thanks Akshay :)

Comment: perfect, glad to help. feel free to upvote and mark the answer if it helped!

Comment: My apologies @Akshay. If you can spare me some time to answer my questions regarding this Autoencoder as I have few knowledge about this.I have used CNN, LSTM, GRU erc models before. We have inputs and corresponding labels in those models. But I don’t see this label cross matching in autoencoder. Can you explain how this thing works in autoencoder ? How autoencoder knows how many classes or labels I have ?

Comment: @AMA, please feel free to check my profile to see how to connect with me. thanks!

Comment: Autoencoders are specifically for data compression. The encoder takes the data, compresses it into latent space, and then the decoder tries to regenerate the input from this compressed representation the encoder is passing to the decoder. In a standard autoencoder that you are trying to develop, there is no utilization class labels, because that's not what an autoencoder is for.